# Proper use of DBNull

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sql-server-2008

Can someone inform me of the proper use of DBNull?  I'm developing an MVC3 project which has this query in the controller.

I have a linq query that returns a field that I know has no value on the first cycle:

```
var qryGetBirthdate = (from c in db.Customer
                              select new
                                   {
                                      c.Birthdate
                                   }
                              ).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the database, Birthdate is a Datetime type which is null.

The check I do for this is wrong:

```
 if ( !DBNull.Value.Equals(qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate))
           {
               DateTime? dob = qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate;
           }
```

I've tried variations from other blogs but can't find the answer.  Basically what I want is to catch the fact that 'qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate' doesn't exist yet.  All I'm getting is the exception that the object isn't set to a reference which I know.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns `null` for a reference type if the sequence is empty. That's the reason for the `NullRefernceException` at `qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate`. So check if it's null:

```
if(qryGetBirthdate != null)
{
    // now you can access it safely
}
```

However, you don't need to create the anonymous type.

```
DateTime? firstBirthdate = (from c in db.Customer 
                             select c.Birthdate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's it!  Thanks Tim.  I realise now I shouldn't be using DBNull with L2S either.   I posted the last comment before you added' "However..."  I like the cleaner version, I'll do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If `BirthDate` is a nullable Datetime SQL type then `c.Birthdate` should be a `DateTime?` in which case you would use:

```
DateTime? dob = qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate;
```

Comment: My point was you can't compare it to DBNull - you can remove the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following.  The variable is probably null and not dbnull.

```
 if (qryGetBirthdate != null && qryGetBirthdate.BirthDate != null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate))
            {
                DateTime? dob = qryGetBirthdate.Birthdate;
            }
```